# How does reputation work on the Area51 proposal page?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

On my Area51 proposal page, I have this diplayed:

[image: reputation1]

But when I go to my account recap, I have this:

[image]

It seems that the "729" reputation is my SO reputation (578) + Area51 reputation (151).

Same for badges.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the proposal page, you have to have over 200 rep on a site for it to count. (With the exception of Area 51, that's always counted.)